# Javascript add individual Image

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
keywords = [
    "http://www.website-for-hair.com/", 
    "http://www.website-for-shoes.com/"
]
var keyword = keywords[Math.floor(Math.random()*keywords.length)]

document.write('<a href="'+keyword+'"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/test.jpg" title="Test Title" /></a>');
```

The above code works perfectly however it spins only the domain. I am now required to add individual images for each website and then output domain+image using `+keyword+` together?

Comment: Don't confuse `java` and `javascript`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis - thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list of lists.

Each list contained in that list would store the URL (position 0, `keywords[random_index][0]`) and its corresponding image source (position 1, `keywords[random_index][1]`).

You should also store the random index that you generate in a variable to ensure you always access the same sublist.

For example:

```
keywords = [
    ["http://www.website-for-hair.com/", "imgA"], 
    ["http://www.website-for-shoes.com/", "imgB"]
]

var random_index = Math.floor(Math.random()*keywords.length);
var keyword = keywords[random_index][0];
var image = keywords[random_index][1];

document.write('<a href='+keyword+'><img src='+image+' title="Test Title" /></a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that's similar to how you did it before:

```
var websites = [
    { url: "http://site1.com", image: "http://site1.com/logo.png" },
    { url: "http://site2.com", image: "http://site2.com/logo.jpg" }
];

var website = websites[Math.floor(Math.random * websites.length)];

document.write(
    '<a href="' + website.url + '">' +
    '<img src="' + website.image + '" title="foo" />' +
    '</a>'
);
```

Comment: Okay Evan, let me try this be right back, thanks for the effort will let you know if this works :)

Comment: @user3134988 It's much preferred to use add HTML via [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) rather than `document.write`